# React Update Self State and call a method on parent component as well

Tags: reactjs

I have written the following react component

```
class RegistrationActivity extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {activity: this.props.activities[0]}
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }
   handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({activity: event.target.value}, () = {
         this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)
      })
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <div>Select Activity</div>
            <div>
               <select onchange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.activity}>
                  {
                  this.props.activities.map((activity, index) => 
                     <option>{activity}</option>
                  )
                  }
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

<RegistrationActivity handleChange={this.handleSelectionChange} activities=["foo", "bar", "baz"] />
```

My objective is as follows

1. At first, the state is set to the first item in the props array (so foo)
2. when selection is changed, the internal state is updated first
3. then once the internal state has been successfully updated, the event handler method of the parent (this.props.handleChange) should be called.

but I get an error

```
SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (45:59)
  43 |          }
  44 |          handleChange(event) {
> 45 |             this.setState({activity: event.target.value}, () = {
     |                                                            ^
  46 |                this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)
  47 |             })
  48 |          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({activity: event.target.value}, () => {
         this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)
      })
   }
```

You have missed `=>` in the function.

To call parent component method from child component then you need to follow below structure.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  triggerFoo() {
    this.foo.toggle();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo ref={foo => this.foo = foo} />
        <Button onClick={this.triggerFoo.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  state = {foo: false}
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      foo: !this.state.foo
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Foo Triggered: {this.state.foo.toString()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        Click This
      </button>
    );
  };
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of an invalid ssyntax for the callback function, you need to use `=>` and not `=`

```
this.setState({activity: event.target.value}, () => {   // => operator here
         this.props.handleChange(event.target.value)
      })
   }
```